# C++ access protected member of base class from friend function of derived class

Tags: c++, class, c++14

## Origional question

MWE: (minimal [not]working example)

```
class base
{
protected:
    int b;
};

class derived : public base
{
    friend void incr();
};

void incr()
{
    base::b ++;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code was created to demonstrate the compiler error I have come across in a much larger project I am working on.

I have a base class with some data members. I then create a derived class to add additional functions to the base class. Some of those functions are friend functions, which I thought would give me access to the protected members of the base class, but apparently not. I implemented these functions as friends becuase they do copy operations between blocks of memory, and it makes more sense syntactically to have them implemented externally.

Is there any way to solve the compiler error (see below) without changing these functions to be members of the derived class, or by adding additional member functions to get/set data. (Which I don't really want to do either because of the added complexity.)

Error produced by g++:

```
./src/main_test.cpp: In function ‘void incr()’:
./src/main_test.cpp:7:9: error: ‘int base::b’ is protected
     int b;
         ^
./src/main_test.cpp:17:11: error: within this context
     base::b ++;
           ^
./src/main_test.cpp:7:9: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘base::b’
     int b;
         ^
./src/main_test.cpp:17:11: error: from this location
     base::b ++;
```

## Solution

I was getting myself confused between member and non-member functions. Non-member function requires an object to operate on as there is no this pointer.

```
class base
{
protected:
    int b;
};

class derived : public base
{
    friend void incr(derived &d);
};

void incr(derived &d)
{
    d.b ++;
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't fail because b is protected.  It fails because: you are trying to change base::b but b isn't static.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes thanks I'd just figured that out myself. need to go and look at my code again and change the example I gave. I've got confused

Comment: @JerryJeremiah not correct. it fails because of both.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  Since the second example in the answer  below still uses friend in the derived class to access the protected method of the base class I don't see How you can say that I was wrong when I said it wasn't failing because it was protected.  It looks like being protected does work.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah not talking about answers but about the question's code. `decltype(base::b) x;` is still ill-formed. If `b` was public, it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have control over base, you could add the friend on the base (which semantically is what you're really trying to do.)

The following code snippet compiles.
A derived class retains the friendship access of its base, without that having to seep down to its own properties. `incr` will not have access to `derived`'s private members.

```
class base
{
protected:
    int b;
    friend void incr();
};

class derived : public base
{
};

derived obj;

void incr()
{
    obj.b ++;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This works too:

```
class base
{
protected:
    int b;
};

class derived : public base
{
    friend void incr();
protected:
    int c;

};

derived obj;

void incr()
{
    obj.b ++;
    obj.c ++;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was writing code that led me to the same question. The main purpose of this setup is that you want the base class to have no knowledge of its derived classes friends...

Comment: Yeah, just reading this again, I guess you're right @lano1106, I wasn't able to read behind the question's intent for some reason